# Opening Multiple Ports on the same pod Guaranteed?

Tags: kubernetes

I am fairly new to Kubernetes.  I am trying to figure out the best structure for a pod that requires configuration depending upon which pod requests its services.

So for example.  Data Stream port might be 8080, this is a stream of data of unknown size. Data is processes as it is received. So I can't really use a REST API with a payload as the payload is a stream which could be days long.

The issue is that I might have 10+ copies of this service, and they need to be configured dynamically upon a client pod connecting to that service.  I would prefer to use a separate port like 9000 to connect to the pod with an XML or INI file type of configuration.

My concern is the following.  Since there is 10 copies and the same pod is making 2 unique requests to a services, are they guaranteed to connect to the same service pod or could they be 2 different ones?  Ultimately, I would want to select a service pod (orchestrator can select, but it be a known IP address now), send a configuration file to 9000, then connect to port 8080 with a data stream for the service to be properly completed.

Comment: What do you mean by "configure"?  What is the actual transport?  On a scale of days it can become likely that routine events could cause a pod to be destroyed (due to redeployment, a node running over capacity, the cluster autoscaler, ...); how does your system recover from this?  In general, requests to a Service will not consistently target the same Pod.

Comment: The stream might be much shorter, but too long to upload via HTTP process as a file and return via the HTTP request.  Hard drive space is likely going to be a problem with that approach. So I use TCP to send a stream in, which processes and responds on the same port.  But I need to first get something like an INI file to that pod before it processes the stream to make sure it is processing it properly.

Comment: Is this a preëxisting system, or something you're designing from scratch?  (Again, on a scale of days, it seems not unlikely that a TCP stream will disconnect for reasons outside your control.)  I can imagine a couple of other transport options that might work more reliably, and I would think hard about how you'd recover if a pod did disappear.  If an HTTP request caused your process to subscribe to a Kafka topic, or request some other resource in blocks using the HTTP `Range:` header, for example, you might not have the "same pod" constraint.

Comment: This is a custom service, the issue is I need to get a configuration INI file into the container before connecting the stream. I can do this, but I need to make sure the same POD is accessed for both the 9000 send INI file followed by the 8080 send data stream.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to open multiple ports for the same service on the same pod, you can assign each port a different name. I’m providing you with a sample yaml file in which a service is communicating outside using both port 80 and port 443.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: my-service
spec:
 selector:
   app: MyApp
 ports:
   - name: http
     protocol: TCP
     port: 80
     targetPort: 9376
   - name: https
     protocol: TCP
     port: 443
     targetPort: 9377
```

For more information and explanation you can refer to this [link](https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/how-to-expose-multiple-port-in-services-in-kubernetes-or-multi-port-services/) from where the above yaml example is provided.

**Update:**

1. @mazecreator I can suggest a workaround for now, attach a temp or
   persistent volume to your service deployment and when you are
   trying to push your configuration files using port 9000 push them
   to this volume and when your application is performing data stream
   operation it will fetch your configs from here and it will be
   completed properly.
2. @mazecreator follow these steps and create separate deployment
   files for each application you are going to deploy in this way all
   the pods related to that particular application can only access
   this volume.

Comment: Thanks, this still might not accomplish what I need in that the multiple ports all need to connect to the same service Pod.  The above configuration will likely give me 2 different service Pods select by round-robin when both 80 and 443 are accessed. A deep dive into Kubernetes Manuals has a specification which I can't fine much information or examples on.  That is Namely: "sessionAffinity: ClientIP", this seems to take care of the problem from within the kubernetes cluster, but problem can exist outside the cluster (direct connect to service).

Comment: @mazecreator I can suggest a workaround for now, attach a temp or persistent volume to your service deployment and when you are trying to push your configuration files using port 9000 push them to this volume and when your application is performing data stream operation it will fetch your configs from here and it will be completed properly.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that, but how do I make sure that only a single Service Pod/Application Pod share the same file?  I couldn't figure that out.  Seemed like if I setup a volume if I had 10 service pods running and all 10 were hit around the same time for the service, wouldn't they all get the same configuration file rather than 10 different ones (each is unique).  Is there a setting I am missing on the Volume creation to make it private.

Comment: @mazecreator follow these [steps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-volume-storage/) and create separate deployment files for each application you are going to deploy in this way all the pods related to that particular application can only access this volume.

Comment: Thank, it still seems like I need to send something to the POD for the file name to access.  So I can store configs on the empty volume, but all service PODs will see all files (all do the same service) so I really need to figure out how to ID that service, but this helps me in the right direction.  Thank you.